# Typescript rename type keys with a string value

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to pass a string & a type and get a returned type with the given string as a prefix like so:

```
type Values = {
  name: "Bob",
  email: "bob@mail.com"
}

// Not sure what "PrefixValues" would look like
type NewValues = PrefixValues<"my", Values>;

Values.name === PrefixedValues.myName
```

is this possible in typescript?

Comment: @jcalz Apologies - I have no idea how that didn't pop up in my SO search thanks for that! I'll close this out

Comment: No need to apologize, duplicates happen!  Good luck!